# Decode a compressed bytes to utf-8 in python?

Tags: python, utf-8

I have a base64 format variable

```
variable = b'gAN9cQAoGdS4='
```

To store in database I decode it

```
st1 = string.decode('utf-8')
st1
Out[35]: 'gAN9cQAoGdS4='
```

Now I have a very large variable more than 4GB, so I compress it using zlib

```
import zlib
variable_comp = zlib.compress(variable)
```

Now to store in db, I can't decode it

```
st1 = variable_comp.decode('utf-8')
```

I get

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 1: invalid start byte
```

so I tried

```
st2 = variable_comp.decode('utf-8', errors="ignore")
```

But when I decompress it, I get error

```
variable_decomp = zlib.decompress(st2)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

may I know the fix for this, whether gzip will fix it?

Comment: Try this, `variable_decomp = zlib.decompress(st2.encode())`. Hope it may help you

Comment: I get error, error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

Comment: As per my understanding you wanted to store a lengthy string in base64 format in DB, correct ? or do you want to store the content as Blob ? if you want to store in DB as base64, first compress your content then convert to base64 and store in DB

Comment: I converted the python object to bytes, then compressed it and then converted to base64 format and decoded, it worked. I can't do that in first place as the python object is an n x n array.